# android how to add two countdowntimer in single activity?

Tags: android

I am using two imageview win which I want to use two countdowntimer.  1 timer shows 1 image at 1000ms ,after that another countdowntimer start and shows 2 image and after second image go on another screen but I have used this with single countdowntimer.  How can I use 2 countdowntimer in my class?  Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView image1,image2;
    CountDownTimer countdown1,countdown2;
    int a = 0; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aaa);

        image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1); 
        image2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2); 

        image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1); 
        image2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2); 
        image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        image2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) { 


            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 


                if(a == 0) 
                { 
                    image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                    image2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
                } 
                else { 

                } a++; 

            } 

            public void onFinish() { 

                image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } 
        }.start();



    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't a++ be in the else junction?

Comment: no, i just found the else part useless. that's why I asked

Comment: no sir..actully i have to use 2 counter in this ,after 1 sec another image shows in 2 counter

Comment: when is the user gonna see the second image if you start an activity right away?

Comment: after 1 sec,user will see another iamge for 3 sec.and after 3 second ,next activity start

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47504/discussion-between-cosmincalistru-and-rajshree)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the request but i would try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView image1,image2;
    int a = 0; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aaa);

        image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1); 
        image2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2); 
        image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        image2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

        new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) { 
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
                if(a == 0) { 
                    image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                } else if(a == 1) { 
                    image1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
                    image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                }
                a++; 
            } 
            public void onFinish() { 
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } 
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @rajshree, you have enough reputation to upvote also can't you upvote also if it helped you.